# Как оценить время передачи HTTP-запроса?

Tags: http

Cколько времени примерно будет идти HTTP-запрос из Москвы до Сиднея и обратно? TCP/IP? UDP?

Какой примерно порядок цифр: сотни микросекунд, единицы миллисекунд, десятки миллисекунд, сотни миллисекунд, единицы секунд, десятки секунд?

Вопрос с собеседования по С++

Comment: Простой русский ping поможет узнать. :-)